# Help with encoding in html page

Tags: html, encoding

I am coding a site, whose main language is Portuguese, which has a lot of 'unusual' chars, like `, ´, ~, and ç.

I if don't use the & directive of HTML, the words appear all messed up on the browser. So I can write a `&aacute;` (e.g) whenever I need to, but that's very troublesome, since the Portuguese language is full of 'unusual' chars, as I mentioned.

I suppose there is a way around this. Which one?

Btw, I have added this to the top of all the pages of the website, but it didn't make any difference.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a meta tag in your `<head>`:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
```

Comment: that worked very nice. but should i use this or is using the HTTPHeaders a better idea?

Answer (score 0):

- [Set your editor](http://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-setting-encoding-in-applications) to save in a known encoding (UTF-8 unless you have a good reason to use something else)
- Specify that encoding in your [HTTP Headers](http://www.w3.org/International/O-HTTP-charset)
- Make sure the encoding doesn't get changed by any program code or database storage along the way.
- Do not use an XML prolog (`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>`), it triggers Quirks mode in IE6

See also:

- [Character encodings for beginners](http://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-what-is-encoding.en)
- [Handling character encodings in HTML and CSS](http://www.w3.org/International/tutorials/tutorial-char-enc/)

Comment: HTTP headers have higher priority.

Comment: thanks for the links, I will take a look. But, what should I use then? Meta tag or HTTPHeaders?